# system can't prompt the user for permission of location services permission in iOS8

Tags: ios8, core-location

When I start location service in iOS 8, the system does not ask user for location permission. After the first launching, my App is not configured in Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services, neither "Never" or "Always". The Core Location framework could not work until manually select "Always" in Settings.

I have tried specifying the "location" value of the UIBackgroundModes key in Info.plist (although my App don't need location when running in background), nothing changed.

What's wrong?

Comment: Problem has been solved by manually calling the CLLocationManager object method requestAlwaysAuthorization. Calling this method requires presence of NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in Info.plist. Thanks to @rmaddy . BTW,  I can't find your first answer.